# Threads work non appropriately

Tags: c, multithreading, struct

threads are new for me. i just tried a code like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
 typedef struct{
  sem_t *s;
  int firstID;
  int secondID;
 } stadium;
 void * game(void * currentData){
  stadium * st = (stadium *)currentData;
sem_wait(st->s);
int first = st->firstID;
int second = st->secondID;
int o = rand();
int t = rand();
printf("%d Team %d:%d %d Team\n",first,o%100009,t%100009,second);
sem_post(st->s);
}
int main(){
for(int  i= 1;i<=10;i++){
    for(int j = i+1;j<=10;j++){
        sem_t s ;
        sem_t c;
        sem_init(&s,0,4);
        sem_init(&c,0,1);
        pthread_t p;
        stadium st;
        st.firstID = i;
        st.secondID = j;
        st.s = &s;
        st.counter = &c;
        pthread_create(&p,NULL,game,&st);
    }
}
pthread_exit(0);
return 0;
 }
```

it prints randomly but somehow it prints the same pairs. how can it print same pair when it only iterates on same pair once?

Comment: You are passing *different* semaphores to each thread. That defeats the purpose of semaphores as it means they are not synchronising with each other. Also, the semaphores are declared *inside* the `for` loop so they go out of scope after the loop ends (at which time the threads are likely not to have run yet). Finally, your main thread does not wait for the child threads to exit - so it will kill all the threads when it exits.

Comment: `stadium st`. That's also an automatic variable that is passed to the threads but that goes out of scope at a time that the child threads may or may not have completed. That is, your code is full of Undefined Behaviour and logic errors.

Comment: @kaylum main will in fact let other threads finish.

Comment: @2501 Really? I had always thought the opposite based on what it says in the [pthread_create manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html): "The new thread terminates in one of the following ways: ... the main thread performs a return from main().  This causes the termination of all threads in the process".

Comment: @kaylum You're basing your conclusion on irrelevant information.

Comment: @2501 Could you expand? I'd like to learn. Are you saying `main` will always wait for all threads to complete or is it particular to this code?

Comment: @kaylum How does main exit?

Comment: @2501 Got you. Thanks for educating me. So just to state it explicitly for others. `main` does not automatically wait for other threads to exit. But calling pthread_exit does ensure that happens. From the [`pthread_exit` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html): "To allow other threads to continue execution, the main thread should terminate by calling pthread_exit()"

Comment: @kaylum Yes....

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'. unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that is visible even with variable width fonts. 2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line and functions by 2 blank lines

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  When compiling the posted code the compiler outputs: 1) error: 'stadium (aka struct anonynous>)' has no member named 'counter'. 2) warning: control reaches end of non-void function 'game()'   (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: for good programming practice, separate the struct definition from the typedef.  (this will require the struct have tag name)

Comment: the main() function is creating 10 threads, 10 times, then not waiting for them to exit (wait should be via calls to `pthread_join()` )  The result is the threads (probably) will not be completed before the whole program is exited.  Note: each thread should be exited via a call to `pthread_exit()`, not just the main() thread  Note: in main() the call to `pthread_exit()` will not return so the statement `return 0;` will never be executed.  Note: `0` is NOT NULL.  in the parameter to `pthread_exit() do not use `0`

Comment: when calling `sem_init()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  For each of the 100 semaphores created by each run of the posted code, there needs to be a call to `sem_destroy()` as semaphores do not 'disappear' just because a program exited.

Comment: the posted code should be using the same semaphore as it is always 'protecting' access to the same set of data.  As it is, nothing is being protected, because the 100 threads are all using separate semaphores or to look at it differently.  the semaphores are being re-initialized on each pass through the inner loop in main().  I.E. a semaphore should only be initialized once.  Strongly suggest placing the semaphore declarations in global file space so they are visible in each thread AND only calling `sem_init()` before going into the loops in main()

Comment: Strongly suggest, after moving the semaphore declarations to the file global space, to remove the pointer to the semaphore from the struct stadium.

Comment: the address of the semaphore `c` is used to set a non existent field `counter` in the local instance of the struct stadium.  and is otherwise completely unused.  Suggest remove the semaphore `c` and the statement: `st.counter = &c;`

Comment: the posted code contains, in function main(), the statement: `pthread_t p;` that is used to save the returned value from a call to `pthread_create()`.   That local variable is destroyed on every iteration of that inner loop. so making any calls to `pthread_join() no workable.  Strongly suggest keeping an array of 100 of `pthread_t` in global file space, setting them at each call to `pthread_create()`  (which the code should be checking the returned value from) and later using those values in the calls to `pthread_join()`

Comment: the posted code logic will not result in unique output lines because the data will either be already destroyed by the next loop of the main function and/or because a thread execution is an asynchronous operation so will be looking at some later version (address has not changed) of the data.  I.E. the semaphores are not helping at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code clean compilers, produces the desired output, has no incorrect/duplicate output values and does not use semaphores.

Using semaphores does not result in a increasing order of the output for all values.

Not using `malloc()` results in duplicate and missing output lines

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define MAX_THREADS (100)
#define MAX_I       (10)
#define MAX_J       (10)

struct myStadium 
{
    int firstID;
    int secondID;
};

typedef struct myStadium stadium;


//sem_t s ;


void * game(void * dummy)
 {
    stadium *st = (stadium*)dummy;

    //sem_wait(&s);
    int o = rand();
    int t = rand();
    printf("%d Team %d:%d %d Team\n",
           st->firstID,
           o%100009,
           t%100009,
           st->secondID );
    free( st );
    //sem_post(&s);
    pthread_exit( NULL );
} // end thread: game

pthread_t p[100] = {0};

int main( void )
{
    //sem_init(&s,0,4);

    for(int i=1; i<=MAX_I; i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1; j<=MAX_J; j++)
        {
            //sem_wait( &s );
            stadium *st = malloc( sizeof( stadium ));
            if( !st )
            {
                perror( "malloc failed" );
            }

            else
            { // else, malloc successful
                st->firstID  = i;
                st->secondID = j;
                if( 0 != pthread_create(&p[i*j],NULL,game, st) )
                {
                    perror( "pthread_create failed" );
                    free( st );
                }
            }
            //sem_post( &s );
        }
    }

    for( int k = 0; k<MAX_THREADS; k++ )
    {
        if( p[k] )
        {
            pthread_join( p[k], NULL );
        }
    }

    int status = 0;
    pthread_exit( &status );

 }
```

With the above code, the output is:

```
1 Team 27014:54674 3 Team
1 Team 41442:82619 5 Team
1 Team 71618:157 4 Team
1 Team 20604:12028 6 Team
1 Team 62973:34366 7 Team
1 Team 10103:68500 8 Team
1 Team 98202:20843 9 Team
1 Team 13740:36869 10 Team
2 Team 57690:44808 3 Team
2 Team 61812:38439 4 Team
2 Team 2061:48433 5 Team
2 Team 76053:1017 6 Team
2 Team 35506:44049 8 Team
2 Team 97788:44099 7 Team
2 Team 81026:60961 9 Team
2 Team 14803:17640 10 Team
3 Team 15627:65854 4 Team
3 Team 9859:96854 5 Team
9 Team 61159:30004 10 Team
3 Team 66011:30464 6 Team
3 Team 18482:28975 7 Team
3 Team 74439:28585 8 Team
3 Team 7075:72632 9 Team
3 Team 59037:30425 10 Team
4 Team 19102:16718 5 Team
4 Team 84842:80914 6 Team
4 Team 64767:86903 7 Team
4 Team 38948:40811 8 Team
4 Team 87921:74454 9 Team
4 Team 94469:95309 10 Team
5 Team 18544:85095 6 Team
5 Team 56261:33347 7 Team
5 Team 2727:71888 8 Team
5 Team 8802:22195 9 Team
6 Team 78342:74813 7 Team
6 Team 62268:96824 8 Team
5 Team 13389:46308 10 Team
6 Team 35009:20464 9 Team
6 Team 18931:94047 10 Team
7 Team 60498:47642 9 Team
7 Team 20365:45332 10 Team
7 Team 38157:94741 8 Team
8 Team 32226:77105 9 Team
8 Team 35543:29747 10 Team
1 Team 25047:79703 2 Team
```